# Mininet Round Robin Load Balancing with Pox Controller

Tags: curl, load, load-balancing, mininet, pox

I'm creating a network in Mininet with 2 servers and 4 hosts and attempting to have the pox controller handle the load balancing. From the hosts, I am using the command `curl 10.0.1.1` (10.0.1.1 being the IP of the pox controller) to see how the controller directs data to 1 of the 2 servers. From what I am reading, this is done in a simple round robin fashion. However, whenever I use the curl command from each of the hosts to send data, I am not getting data evenly distributed between server 1 and server 2. Since it is round robin, the controller should send data to each server one after another. In reality, it is sending data to a server maybe 1-3x in a row and then the other 1-3x. In the long run, data is distributed fairly evenly though.

Is this the result I'm suppose to be expecting? Shouldn't data be sent to server 1 then 2 then 1 then 2 and so forth?